# Synonym request: CAN and CAN-Bus

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can) and [can-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus) mean exactly the same thing and are unambiguous.

Users with 2500+ rep please vote on synonym request here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/can/synonyms

Comment: CAN can be CAN-Bus

Comment: [I mean, you don't do a great job of selling me on this, but *fiiiine*....](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)

Comment: I'm familiar with the interface and can confirm that a tag merge is appropriate. I'm happy to action this, but I need someone who can quickly look through the ~500 questions tagged [[tag:can]] to make sure they're all about the protocol, not "Can I do x?". I don't have time to do it at the moment.

Comment: @CodyGray You needn't do all. That would be exhaustive. Looking for some keywords in posts would be enough. (You can easily find non CAN-bus related posts like these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302373/content-addressable-network)

Comment: I'd happily vote for the synonym, but 790K rep is not enough.  You could post comments to users that do have 5 helpful votes in the tag to get them to vote, but let's volunteer @Cody to cut that short.

Comment: @Makoto If you don't even know what it is, then obviously you shouldn't be casting any votes... I believe that's the whole point of the current tag synonym mechanic.

Comment: @Lundin:  No doubt that I'm unable to do anything, but again - as a layman, you're not really doing much to convince others who *don't* know what this is that this is a good synonym.  It only took me a minute to look for that information, but *still*...

Comment: @Makoto I'm basically asking something equivalent to "make USB synonymous with Universal Serial Bus" here. Personally I don't go around worrying my pretty head about Javascript jQuery JSP PHP ASP HTML... web... thingies. I let those who have a clue about that stuff handle those tags. Rather than merrily proposing that we make Java and Javascript synonymous - it's all web fluff to me, how different can it be! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I CAN and I did: **[can-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus) ← [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can)**

I picked [can-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can-bus) as the "master" tag to hopefully stave off rampant misuse of a generic-sounding [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/can) tag. (Yeah, yeah, we have tag descriptions, but let's not kid ourselves—nobody reads those.)

Speaking of tag wikis, both of them were plagiarized from Wikipedia, so if someone has a few minutes to kill, writing a tag wiki would be a semi-useful way of doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the wiki and wrote down some tag usage advise.

Comment: Good choice (of can-bus as the master). Now we just need [the electronics site to follow along](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/can).

Comment: Just for the record, I have been closely following and actively moderating this tag since we changed this in February, 4 months ago. This change fixed every problem with the tag. There's been pretty much been 100% relevant, on-topic questions posted below the tag since the change. Good stuff.